# Stop the page jumping to top when reload

Tags: javascript

I am designing a website with a sticky menubar. I am trying to make the page stick to the content area when realoaded or when clicked somewhere on the menu bar and it keeps jumping to the top.

Comment: Do you have some code? Can you show what you've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a few ways to skin this cat but linking with a page element id may help return a user to where you want them?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;

  var stickyNav = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
      $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('.nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  };

  stickyNav();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyNav();
  });
});
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#lastParagraph">Bottom Paragraph</a>
    <a href="#nearTop">Near Top</a>
    <a href="http://mysitesomewhere.com/index.html#idNearTheBottom">somewhere else</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget nunc nec magna sollicitudin consequat. Nunc ornare ut leo ac aliquam. Vivamus hendrerit cursus lacinia. Mauris sagittis leo at nunc scelerisque molestie. Aliquam condimentum ante
      urna, a ullamcorper sapien pulvinar at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean nec elit sed orci interdum varius at nec mi. Phasellus tempus vulputate purus in mollis. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur
      mauris magna, laoreet at orci semper, tristique blandit massa. Etiam eleifend ornare tellus tempus accumsan. Nunc mollis nisl sit amet enim iaculis, in placerat felis porta.</p>
    
        <p id="nearTop">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget nunc nec magna sollicitudin consequat. Nunc ornare ut leo ac aliquam. Vivamus hendrerit cursus lacinia. Mauris sagittis leo at nunc scelerisque molestie. Aliquam condimentum ante
      urna, a ullamcorper sapien pulvinar at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean nec elit sed orci interdum varius at nec mi. Phasellus tempus vulputate purus in mollis. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur
      mauris magna, laoreet at orci semper, tristique blandit massa. Etiam eleifend ornare tellus tempus accumsan. Nunc mollis nisl sit amet enim iaculis, in placerat felis porta.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget nunc nec magna sollicitudin consequat. Nunc ornare ut leo ac aliquam. Vivamus hendrerit cursus lacinia. Mauris sagittis leo at nunc scelerisque molestie. Aliquam condimentum ante
      urna, a ullamcorper sapien pulvinar at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean nec elit sed orci interdum varius at nec mi. Phasellus tempus vulputate purus in mollis. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur
      mauris magna, laoreet at orci semper, tristique blandit massa. Etiam eleifend ornare tellus tempus accumsan. Nunc mollis nisl sit amet enim iaculis, in placerat felis porta.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget nunc nec magna sollicitudin consequat. Nunc ornare ut leo ac aliquam. Vivamus hendrerit cursus lacinia. Mauris sagittis leo at nunc scelerisque molestie. Aliquam condimentum ante
      urna, a ullamcorper sapien pulvinar at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean nec elit sed orci interdum varius at nec mi. Phasellus tempus vulputate purus in mollis. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur
      mauris magna, laoreet at orci semper, tristique blandit massa. Etiam eleifend ornare tellus tempus accumsan. Nunc mollis nisl sit amet enim iaculis, in placerat felis porta.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget nunc nec magna sollicitudin consequat. Nunc ornare ut leo ac aliquam. Vivamus hendrerit cursus lacinia. Mauris sagittis leo at nunc scelerisque molestie. Aliquam condimentum ante
      urna, a ullamcorper sapien pulvinar at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean nec elit sed orci interdum varius at nec mi. Phasellus tempus vulputate purus in mollis. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur
      mauris magna, laoreet at orci semper, tristique blandit massa. Etiam eleifend ornare tellus tempus accumsan. Nunc mollis nisl sit amet enim iaculis, in placerat felis porta.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget nunc nec magna sollicitudin consequat. Nunc ornare ut leo ac aliquam. Vivamus hendrerit cursus lacinia. Mauris sagittis leo at nunc scelerisque molestie. Aliquam condimentum ante
      urna, a ullamcorper sapien pulvinar at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean nec elit sed orci interdum varius at nec mi. Phasellus tempus vulputate purus in mollis. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur
      mauris magna, laoreet at orci semper, tristique blandit massa. Etiam eleifend ornare tellus tempus accumsan. Nunc mollis nisl sit amet enim iaculis, in placerat felis porta.</p>

    <p id="lastParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget nunc nec magna sollicitudin consequat. Nunc ornare ut leo ac aliquam. Vivamus hendrerit cursus lacinia. Mauris sagittis leo at nunc scelerisque molestie. Aliquam condimentum ante
      urna, a ullamcorper sapien pulvinar at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean nec elit sed orci interdum varius at nec mi. Phasellus tempus vulputate purus in mollis. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur
      mauris magna, laoreet at orci semper, tristique blandit massa. Etiam eleifend ornare tellus tempus accumsan. Nunc mollis nisl sit amet enim iaculis, in placerat felis porta.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hints would be:

- avoiding reloading the page, by doing a Single Page Application (basically, with javascript, you fetch the new content and insert it in the page without reloading)
- with some javascript, keep track of where the user is on the page, and put that information (y position) in the links in your menubar. Then, on load, another JS script get that information and scrolls. But that's a bit dirty.
- Using anchors (#) and ids in your link so that the browser automatically scrolls the user to a part of the page